# How to validate a list of elements of specific type in marshmallow?

Tags: post, flask, flask-restful, marshmallow, flask-marshmallow

I have a POST endpoint in flask which takes a json data which contains a key - `collections` which has a list as value which in turn contains list of dictionaries containing specific keys in it.

I'm trying to validate the `request.json` but couldn't find a proper way to do it.

Here's the code for marshmallow schemas:

```
class RowSchema(Schema):
    nationalCustomerId = fields.Int(required=True)
    storeId = fields.Int(required=True)
    categoryId = fields.Int(required=True)
    deliveryDate = fields.Date(required=True, format="%Y-%m-%d")

class RequestSchema(Schema):
    combinations = fields.List(RowSchema)
```

I was trying to validate the `request.json` with `RequestSchema`.

The `request.json` I'm sending is like below:

```
{
    "combinations": [
            {
                "nationalCustomerId": 1,
                "storeId": 1,
                "categoryId": 1,
                "deliveryDate": "2020-01-20"
            }
        ]
}
```

Where am I making mistake?

This is the error I'm getting:

> ValueError: The list elements must be a subclass or instance of
>   marshmallow.base.FieldABC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the `fields.Nested` inside `fields.List`

```
class RowSchema(Schema):
    nationalCustomerId = fields.Int(required=True)
    storeId = fields.Int(required=True)
    categoryId = fields.Int(required=True)
    deliveryDate = fields.Date(required=True, format="%Y-%m-%d")

class RequestSchema(Schema):
    combinations = fields.List(fields.Nested(RowSchema))
```